# Set time of first chunk when convert video to hls using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, hls

I'm using ffmepg to convert video to hls stream. 
For current i can set time of each chunk by using **-segment_time** parameter but i want to set time of first chunk (different than other chunk).

I wonder can i do that?

Comment: You mean you want the first chunk to have a different length? Why would you need this, if I may ask?

Comment: @slhck yes. i want first chunk have different length. because i store first chunk different than other chunk. so i want to make it different length to handle it easier.

Comment: You can use `-segment_times` to specify individual durations.

Comment: oh. that's right. it's what i need. thank you

Answer (score 0):

While `-segment_time` controls each segment's duration, you can use [`-segment_times`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) with a comma-separated list of per-segment durations.